# Need to simplify a logarithmic expression

Tags: logarithms

Can someone simplify this ($\log$ here refers to the common logarithm)?
$$\sqrt{4\log2+(\log5)^2} + \sqrt{4\log5+(\log2)^2}$$
I know this has a simple solution but I cannot find it.

Comment: Equations have solutions. Expressions do not. What you wrote is an expression and has no solution (the concept of a solution does not exist for it). Your question is like saying "What is the solution of $\pi$?"

Comment: Do you mean ".... $= 0$"? Or do you mean to simplify the expression?

Comment: Because that would make a lot more sense.

Comment: yes, I mean to simplify and find what it is equal to

Comment: Do you have reason to believe this gets any simpler than it already is?

Comment: yes, I even know that it is equal to 3 :D (I have the answer key) I just cannot understand how

Comment: Apparently WolframAlpha disagrees with the answer of $3$ : http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%5Csqrt%7B4%5Clog2%2B%28%5Clog5%29%28%5Clog5%29%7D+%2B+%5Csqrt%7B4%5Clog5%2B%28%5Clog2%29%28%5Clog2%29%7D, if you took $\log$ of base 10 instead of the natural $\log$.

Comment: @YiyuanLee click the "use the base 10 logarithm instead" option.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It seems pretty sneaky.  So I'm guessing those are common logs.  Let's take a look at the first square root.  We have

$$\sqrt{4\log2+(\log5)^2}=\sqrt{4(\log 10-\log5)+(\log5)^2}=\sqrt{4-4\log5+(\log5)^2}=2-\log 5$$

Similarly, the second square root yields $2-\log 2$.  Sum them together to get $4-\log10=3$.

Comment: @user136727 No problem.  I'm honestly surprised it simplified that much.

Comment: good catch on the common log. I was puzzling how one could simplify that at all using the natural log. On a math site, I assume natural unless labelled otherwise. Sneaky, indeed! (+1)